# Merge [android-architecture-livedata] with [android-livedata]

Tags: discussion, tags

[android-architecture-livedata](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/android-architecture-livedata) 111 questions.

[android-livedata](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/android-livedata) 520 questions, and has a full information section.

I would suggest that [android-architecture-livedata](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/android-architecture-livedata) be merged into [android-livedata](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/android-livedata).

Synonym? Burninate?

Comment: It seems no coincidence that these tag communities have such horrible answer rates.  This kind of [everyhing-and-the-kitchen-sink] tagging practices just create little islands where nobody can find each other anymore.  [angular] is another one.  Why questioners don't use [android][livedata] is murky, I'd guess they actually do and it is just one or a few users that retag them to create their own all-your-base-belong-to-me island.  Consider to ping Sagar to join this discusson.

Comment: I think we could happily just use [tag:livedata] since the only usage of a livedata tag is related to Android. Anything else just muddies the waters.